# Software for MPEG-TS analysis and ETR 101 290 monitoring under linux

Tags: linux, ubuntu, video-streaming, mpeg2-ts, dvb

I'm working with a Cable TV company at the moment and we want to get a ubuntu box on a remote head end where all our feeds are flying over IP on multicast. What we would like to do with this machine (apart from wireshark the multicast) is to be able to analyze the streams on the fly. I know about DVBSnoop, but I have not been able to listen to the stream on multicast as it flies on the network, the other problem is that we want to hand this down to users who will (lets just say) prefer a GUI. So I wonder if there's anything (commercial or FLOSS) that will give us at least a similar feature set like [TSReader](http://www.tsreader.com/tsreader/).

When it comes to ETR 101 290 monitoring I haven't seen anything under linux, does anyone know of any software? even if it's software that would work under wine we might be able to get away with it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not remotely FLOSS, but [MP2TSAE](http://www.manzanitasystems.com/products/transport-stream-analyzer.html) from Manzanita systems runs on Linux (it says [here](http://www.manzanitasystems.com/products/ts-analyzer-specs.html)) and can analyse IP streams in real time (it says [here](http://www.manzanitasystems.com/products/ts-analyzer-features.html)). Never used it myself, but I've used their MP2TSME multiplexer and it's generally a solid product with good support.

Answer (score 0):

For software-based IPTV MPEG transport monitoring in line with ETR 101 290, you can check out http://www.netrounds.com. It provides both MPEG-capable software agents for Ubuntu/Linux as well as a complete probe appliance for virtual or bare metal hardware. Probes/agents are remotely controlled through a portal in the public cloud, where live monitoring results and alarm management are also available.

There is a free version available that supports monitoring of two transport streams (channels) concurrently. Channels are received by the probe/agent by IGMP join messages sent to the corresponding multicast groups.

DISCLAIMER: I am affiliated with Netrounds.

Answer (score 0):

Kinda late to the party, but you could also check out Ineoquest IQDVx software. I believe it only runs on windows though....but it is GUI based. Nice and user friendly.

Answer (score 0):

You can try [www.3way.com.ar](http://www.3way.com.ar) is a complete set of tools for **Transport Stream monitoring** and analyse.

Including recording of each program and had a option for Multiviewer. Run on Linux.